# Chrome API (chrome.topSites.get) is not ready during browser start

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Did anyone get a situation when chrome API didn't available during browser start

I have catch the situation when I didn't get "callback happen" in log only during browser start on one test computer

chrome.topSites.get(function(data) {
  console.log("callback happen");
});

Comment: where is this code placed? In a background script or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

add `topSites` in permission tab

### manifest.json

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab", 
    "topSites", << Add this 
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
],

 "browser_action": {
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
}
```

and in **popup.html** add js file and write

```
chrome.topSites.get(function(t) { console.log('Here I am inside topSites')});
```

it's working on my side.

Comment: Err, what? Completely different API.

Comment: oops! mismatched .Sorry